# Temperature as function of 2D-point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

We are located in the point $P(3,4)$ where the temperature $T(x,y)$ in and around P is given by

$$T(x, y) = \frac{100y}{x^2+y^2}$$

We want to find the change in temperatures in different directions.

a) How big is the temperature change in the direction $\vec r = [1, -2]$?

b) In which direction do we need to move to experience the greatest increase in temperatures? How big is the change in temperatures in this direction? Ditto for smallest change in temperatures.

**My thoughts**

The whole problem seems like I should be differentiating $T$, but beyond that, I don't see where to start. It also seems like gradients should be involved, but I haven't been formally introduced to them, though I'm familiar with what they represent.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For this question, it is important you make this distinction:

> The derivative at a point, is a *linear transformation*, which gives the rate and direction of change at the point of evaluation.

How do we evaluate this derivative? Well, we take the *partial* derivatives, and put them together as components, to get the transformation. Then given a vector, we can apply this to that vector.

In this case, we see that the directional derivatives for $x$ and $y$ are: (you can verify this, if you don't know how to calculate then pop a comment)
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = \frac{-200xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = \frac{100(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
Now, all we are supposed  to do, is to find this quantity when $(x,y)=(3,4)$. Substituting, we see that $\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x},\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\right)(3,4) =(-3.84,1.12)$. So this is your linear transformation, and the derivative of $T$ at $3,4$.

Finally, to get the magnitude of movement in the direction $(1,-2)$, we just have to take a dot product: $(-3.84,1.12)(1,-2) = -6.08$. The magnitude would count as $6.08$ then. However, since $[1,-2]$ should be a unit direction, we have to divide by $\sqrt{1^2 + (-2)^2}$, so that would give $\frac{6.08}5 = 1.216$ as the answer.

The direction to move in, in order to experience maximum temperature change, is in fact the same problem as maximizing $|3.84x+1.12y|$, for a direction $[x,y]$.

Take this as gospel for the time being, you will surely find a proof online:

> The maximum change is along the gradient itself.

That is to say, you will find maximum change along the direction $[3.84,-1.12]$!

Evaluating the change at this point, it is $16$, which we need to normalize by dividing by $\sqrt{(3.84)^2 + (-1.12)^2} = 4$, so after dividing we see that the rate of change in the direction $[3.84,,-1.12]$ is $4$, and this is the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea try calculate the directional derivative in a arbitrary direction (by definition).

Let $v=(a,b)$ with $\|v\|^2=a^2+b^2=1$ be a direction, we have that
$$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial v}(P) = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{T(P+tv)-T(P)}{t}$$
Then $$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial v}(3,4) = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{T(3+ta,4+tb)-T(3,4)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{100(4+tb)}{(3+ta)^2+(4+tb)^2}-\dfrac{100\cdot 4}{3^2+4^2}}{t} \text{ etc...}$$